# how to list student names from a text file in python

Tags: python

Every time I write a code I keep getting error. here is the code I have

```
def main():
    outflow = open("studentList.txt", "r")
    for line in outflile:
        line[:-1].split(" ")
        print(line)

main()
```

Comment: Design and implement a Python program, which will read student's names from the file and display the list on the screen containing the name of the student and acronym of student name initials. here is the question

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `split()` returns a list, you need to assign the result somewhere.

Comment: If you want to remove the newline at the end of line, use `line.rstrip("\n")`. Using the slice will cause problems if the last line of the file doesn't end with newline, sine you'll remove the last character of the line.

Comment: `outflile` is a typo for `outflow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `studentList` file contain the name of the student one per each line so the way of reading is:

```
def main():
    noOfStudents = 0
    outflow = open("studentList.txt", "r")
    for line in outflow:
        noOfStudents+=1
        print(line.rstrip("\n"))
    print("Total no of students is :", noOfStudents)    
    outflow.close()

main()
```

Output:

```
student A
student B
student C
Total no of students is : 3
```

Comment: how can I add display the number of the students in the class.to my code? I am having trouble with that

Comment: You can simply count no of students i am editing my code you can see my code again

Comment: i fiqured it out now i just need to add acronym of student name initials

Answer (score 0):

If students names are in line by line in the text file then use this

```
filename = "studentList.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

print(lines)
```

or if students names are separated from space then use the following one

```
filename = "studentList.txt"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
     lines = f.read().encode("utf-8").replace(" ", "\n")
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not have any `outflile` (probably a typo) difined this will raise `NameError`, so you can use:

```
def main():
    outflow = open("studentList.txt", "r")
    for line in outflow:
        line[:-1].split(" ")
        print(line)

main()
```

even better:

```
with open("studentList.txt", "r") as outflow:

    for line in outflow:
        line = line.rstrip().split(" ")
        print(line)
```

Comment: outflile is a typo for outflow

Comment: @JessicaFisch well, this may be a reason for another question, if this post useful you can upvote :)